# Ajax (with jQuery) doesn't return data well

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just wrote this code (just an example..):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "users/say_hello_id",
    data: {id : 1},
    success:function(data){ 
        alert(data)
        $("#users").append(data);       
    }
});
```

PHP file just take the name of the user with the id 1, add it 'hello' and then:

```
echo '<tr>hello' . $name . '</tr>';
```

The alert is working well, I see `hello $name`, but why doesn't the `append` work? There isn't mistake with the syntax, I wrote in the append any string and it works well.

**EDIT:**

`#users` exists.

```
<td id="users"></td>
```

**EDIT 2**
I edited the php `echo`. maybe the problem is with the output (includes tags.. html..)?

Comment: Yes. if I write instead of `data` any string it works.

Comment: See if there is any JS Error ? Browser is pointing ....

Comment: There isn't any error. with alert() data is displayed, with append no.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's html you're returning, try

```
dataType: 'html'
```

Comment: I tried it.. but it doesn't work.. I put it between `type` and `url`.

Answer (score 0):

`#users` has to exist.

If you're not sure, try to encapsulate your code into

```
$(function(){

});
```

to be sure it's executed after DOM is ready

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `$("#users").append(data)` with `$("#users").text(data)` or `$("#users").html(data)`.

Comment: Interesting that one works and not the other. Still, I'm glad you found a solution.

Comment: I didn't find a solution, I should use `append` :-)